# rest api from javascript to handle session and security

Tags: rest, session-state

I'm developing a public rest api and want to use it for my company's web client as well (jquery). That would work since it would be on the same server.

Howerver, my question is whether rest is even supposed to be consumed by JavaScript? What about authentication and authorization and session information. Since rest is not supposed to maintain any session state.

1. Can I store all the state, create the response with the token etc within JavaScript?
2. or should I create another plain servlet layer ontop of my own rest api as a rest client which could be richer (break rest principles)
3. Create an extra version for the rest api that allows some less rest-like behavior (session data) and maybe even keep that private.

as a side question I'm also wondering if there's any performance difference between using say Jersey vs regular servlets processing calls? In other words, can I use Jersey as a servlet replacement (to take advantage of the format conversions).